# Binary search tree insertion assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att

I have a binary search tree represented in the following manner:

```
root:
        .quad   A
A:
        .quad   20
        .quad   B
        .quad   C
B:
        .quad   -4
        .quad   0
        .quad   D
C:
        .quad   26
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
D:
        .quad   -3
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
```

Each label has contains the "struct" `value, *left_son, *right_son` (in that order).
I am given a new node, for example:

```
new_node:
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
```

And I need to insert that node in the suiting place for it to remain a binary search tree.

Note that if one of the fields of left\right son is 0 that means that it's a leaf (0=null).

This is how I tried to approach it

```
.global _start

.section .text
_start:
    movq $root, %rax
    cmp $0, %rax
    je empty_tree
    movq $new_node, %rbx
traverse:
    cmpq %rax, %rbx
    je end #if root ==  new_node
    movq %rax, %rcx #backup
    jl left
    jmp right
left:
    movq 8(%rax), %rax
    cmp $0, %rax #reached a leaf
    jne traverse
    movq $new_node, 8(%rcx)
    jmp end
right:
    movq 16(%rax), %rax
    cmp $0, %rax #reached a leaf
    jne traverse
    movq $new_node, 16(%rcx)
    jmp end
empty_tree:
    movq $new_node, root
    jmp end
    
end:
```

But it fails the tests and I can't figure out why.

Comment: The comparison `cmpq %rax, %rbx` at `traverse:` looks suspicious, since `%rax` appears to contain the address of a node, while `%rbx` appears to contain the value stored at a node.

Comment: at `_start` I just changed it to `movq $new_node, %rbx`  (you were right) but still the test fails

Comment: @Michael by changing also to `movq $root, %rax` it solves the problem.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The value at `root` is an address, so it seems to me like it ought to be `movq root, %rax`. But it's not clear to me if you want to compare addresses or values at `traverse`. If you want to compare values, then you need at least one extra `mov`, as well as a change to the `cmp`.

Comment: @Michael In `traverse` I intended to compare the values.
Could you elaborate on why would I need one extra `mov` and where?

Comment: Well, if `%rax` and `%rbx` both contain node addresses but you want to compare the values at those nodes, then obviously you can't compare `%rax` and `%rbx` directly. You need something like `movq (%rbx),%rdx` `cmpq (%rax),%rdx`

Comment: it works.
Just to make sure I completely understand, when I put `()` on a register inside a `mov` command I move the value? and if I'm not I move the address?

Comment: Yes, that's how AT&T syntax for memory addressing modes vs. registers works.  Or to access static data, `mov root(%rip), %rax` is preferred over `mov root, %rax`; use the RIP-relative addressing mode in 64-bit code instead of absolute address, when you're not using any general-purpose register.